# Unwanted Roundings with Math.Pow

Tags: c#

I'm doing some simple calculations and the value entered in a calculator gives me 1.000243872 but it gives me 1. I require the decimal Points. Was wondering what may be the issue for the rounding?

Private Decimal APR = 4.5, Private Decimal PF = 2, Private Decimal CF = 2

```
var value = (double) (1 + (double) APR/(double) PF); => 1.04550625
var value1 = (double)Math.Pow((double)value, (double) CF); =>  1.093083319
var value2 = (double) Math.Pow((double) value1, (double)(1/365)); => 1
```

Comment: Standard C# bug, 1/365 == 0.  You need to use 1.0/365 to get floating point division instead of integer division.

Comment: Would you like to post an answer bud =) @HansPassant

Comment: A little more time spent in the debugger working through the calculations should have pinned this down.

Comment: I don't think its a bug, its an integer division. Some algorithms make use of this property. It can be confusing, and it must be said that you can question this behavior in such a high-level language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dividing two `int` values : `1` and `365`. In most programming languages, this division returns an `int` value, which in your particular case is 0. The `(double)` cast is performed only after the result has been computed. `(double)0` is `0`. To get a fractionary result, you could either use a cast on one of the operands : `(double)1/365` or `1/(double)365`, or use what others have suggested : `1.0/365` or `1/365.0`.

Comment: `(double)1/365` or `1/(double)365` looks ugly(for me), I'd rather prefer `1/365d` or more clearer `1d/365d`.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel you're right, of course, I forgot about that possibility.

Answer (score 2):

1/365 is 0 (it's almost 0, but then becomes 0 because you are dealing with integers inputs therefore you only get the integer result), then casted to a double it's still 0 and anything ^0 = 1

you could try 1.0 / 365

Comment: 1/365 is not (almost) 0, it is always 0 because of integer division